# Self-calibrate sensor measurements with linear regression

Tags: regression, interpretation, calibration

I have measurements of 3 sensors (A, B, C) over variable W. [Reproducible code](https://gist.github.com/emerrf/0cd608779f246187286979d5378f8362).
[image]
The sensors may be wrongly calibrated so before analysing the data I correct the values for each sensor. The correction method compares the values of sensor A vs the mean of A, B and C (ABC, in black) and fit a linear regression. It is expected that the mean of A should be the same as ABC. Here is the R code and the plot (identity in red).

```
# Perform calibration
# Find gain and offset
lmA <- lm(A ~ ABC, data = df)

offsetA <- coefficients(summary(lmA))["(Intercept)", "Estimate"]
gainA <- coefficients(summary(lmA))["ABC", "Estimate"]

# Measurements corrected
df$Ac <- (df$A - offsetA) / gainA
```

[image]

Then, I normalise the corrected value with the mean, so the our reference is now 1.

```
# Normalise with mean
df$Acn <- df$Ac / df$ABC
```

However, when I plot A corrected and normalised over the ABC mean and fit a linear model, I don't see a flat line at 1. Why? The slope has not statistical relevance (p-value ~ 0.54) which is fine but why are there some residuals when the variable is divided by the mean?
[image]

I thought it was due to numerical errors but I scaled down the values but I obtained the same results.

Comment: It looks to me as if the sensors do not produce an exactly linear response. The normalized plot varies from 0.997 to 1.002, or from -0.3 percent to +0.2 percent. Based on the shape of the points (tiny) dispersion around 1.0, I suggest making a test using a quadratic equation rather than a straight line.